# VB.Net Alternative to C# Underscore (discard)

Tags: vb.net

In c# i can do:

`_ = Bla();`

Can I do that in VB.Net ?

I think the answer is no but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: If you want a good *understanding* as **to why vb doesn't support discards** [please](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/346) see that nice thread about it.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: Thanks for the link. Since you did not write an answer yourself, I have just shamelessly stolen it for mine. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The underscore (`_`), as used in your example, is C#'s [discard token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards). Unfortunately, there is (currently) nothing similar in VB. There is a [discussion about adding a similar feature](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/346) on the VB language design github page.

In your example, however, you can just omit assigning the result (both in C# and VB), i.e.

```cs
Bla(); // C#
```

```vb
Bla()  ' VB
```

---

The "discard variable" is particularly useful for `out` parameters. In VB, you can just pass an arbitrary *value* instead of a variable to discard unused `ByRef` parameters. Let me give you an example:

The following two lines are invalid in C#:

```cs
var b = Int32.TryParse("3", 0); // won't compile
var b = Int32.TryParse("3", out 0); // won't compile
```

Starting with C# 7, you can use `_` for that purpose:

```cs
var b = Int32.TryParse("3", out _); // compiles and discards the out parameter
```

This, however, is perfectly valid in VB, even with `Option Strict On`:

```vb
Dim b = Int32.TryParse("3", 0)
```

So, yes, it would be nice to make the fact that "I want to ignore the ByRef value" more explicit, but there is a simple workaround in VB.NET. Obviously, once VB.NET gets [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) or [deconstructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct), this workaround won't be enough.

Comment: Starting with C# 7.0, C# supports discards [Discards - C# Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards). (Note, I'm not the downvoter). Maybe you meant to say that there is no discard variable in VB?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes did you see the link already in the post, it's the same link you posted...

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Thanks for the feedback! I know that, but my first sentence could be misunderstood. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Okay, the new sentence is much better.

Comment: @Heinzi: "In VB, you will have to use a dummy local variable to discard unused ByRef values." I don't get what you mean, in VB i just do nothing when I don't need a ByRef value.

Comment: @Christoph: You are absolutely right, give me a minute to fix my answer.

Comment: @Christoph: Updated my answer. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @Heinzi I think Christoph meant `Dim b = Int32.TryParse("3", Nothing)` as it better shows the intent.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I see the point, but I really don't like to use `Nothing` in a value type context (i.e. in a context where it is *not* equal to C#'s `null`), so I'll leave it at `0` in my example.

Comment: @Andrew Morton: No, I would not use ```Nothing```, I agree with Heinzi that with non-nullable value types that feels odd.

Comment: @Heinzi Could you go onto more detail on "Obviously, once VB.NET gets pattern matching or deconstructors, this workaround won't be enough."? Why is that? I believe I get the case with pattern matching, as 0 will not match most types. But what about deconstructors?

Comment: @Maddin: How would you translate, for example, `if (myTuple is (_, "WITHDRAWAL", var amount))` to VB.NET without a discard operator?